# Infer constraints for both if and else of type equality

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-families

I am trying to fill the hole in the following snippet

```
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Type.Equality
import Data.Type.Bool
import Unsafe.Coerce

ifThenElse :: forall (a :: Nat) (b :: Nat) x l r.
  (KnownNat a, KnownNat b, x ~ If (a==b) l r) =>
  Proxy a -> Proxy b -> Either (x :~: l) (x :~: r)
ifThenElse pa pb = case sameNat pa pb of
  Just Refl -> Left Refl
  Nothing -> Right $ unsafeCoerce Refl -- This was the hole
```

Is it possible?

Edit: Checked the source of [`sameNat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#v:sameNat) and it turns out they use `unsafeCoerce`. I edited the code above accordingly.

Comment: You should probably post your edit as an answer (and roll-back the edit).

Comment: The general issue seems to be that, while GADT pattern matching provides equality constraints, it never provides inequality constraints, so we can't convince GHC that the first clause of the closed type family is not taken. We probably need more support from GHC to do that in the future, AFAICS.

Comment: Ugh, you can tell just from looking at the type that this isn't going to be easy to prove, even with an inductive `Nat` (rather than the broken one in `GHC.TypeLits`). How did you manage to paint yourself into this particular corner? We might be able to advise you on how to redesign your program so that you don't need such gnarly proofs.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I 've been rewriting this over and over for a few days so suggestions are indeed welcome. I am building a `Generic1` typeclass that should have the structure `E s = E0 s | E1 O1 (E s) | E2 O2 (E s) | ...` I have implemented various generic functionalities over this so it seems to be working. I want a safe way to extract the `Oi`s from a given arity `i` in a type safe way. So (for some notion of `i :: Nat`) `getOp :: Proxy i -> e s -> Maybe (OpType i e)`. Since `i` is known at compile time GHC can (and does) infer what the exact type of the above signature on each call site is.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson so here is the problem: I need to traverse the tree with type level `Nat` (which can be easily converted from arity to tree depth) because GHC needs to be able to typecheck each step, so I need to tell her (I see it as a mother fiure) how to figure out the types.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson The heart of the problem is when traversing the (roughly) `(Op :*: recur) :+: rest` whose type is derived from `If (c==n) Op (OpType' (c+1) n rest)`. `c` is the current depth, n is the target depth, I keep track of `n` and increment `c` instead of decrementing `n` because I feel more comfortable incrementing than decrementing GHC's notion of naturals. In the `c==n` case GHC can figure out that the type is `Op` and typecheck everything. Otherwise she can't prove that `c==n` and complains about typechecking.

Comment: Maybe I should edit the question with all this info but I think it's context that is not really central to the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) library to get term-level functions representing the type-level ones (or vice-versa).

The gist of it is:

```
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
```

(...)

```
case (sing :: Sing a) %:== (sing :: Sing b) of
  STrue  -> Left Refl
  SFalse -> Right Refl
```

I've put up a [self-contained file](https://gist.github.com/gallais/df9f598e576caadf1321275cacf996f7) with all the imports and language extensions too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is `%:==` undocumented? I can't find it.

Comment: `Data.Singletons.Prelude` re-exports `Data.Singletons.Prelude.Eq` where you can find [`(%:==)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.2/docs/Data-Singletons-Prelude-Eq.html#v:-37-:-61--61-)