# Infer constraints of type families from constraints of arguments

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass, type-families

I have a bunch of complicated type level functions that evaluate to things like:

```
(If (EqNat n 2)
  1
  (If (EqNat n 1)
    2
    (If (EqNat n 0) 3 0)))
```

Now obviously in this case this expression is a `KnownNat`. More
generally we may say:

```
forall (c :: * -> Constraint) (p :: Bool) a b .
(c a, c b) => c (If p a b)
```

Is there a way to teach GHC to infer this?

Edit: @chi noted that in some cases this is solvable with GADTs but my
particular case is this one:

```
module M1 (C(..)) where

type familiy NestedIfs (n :: Nat) :: Nat
type NestedIfs n = <<complex nested ifs like the above that evals to literals>>

class C a (n :: Nat) where
  f :: KnownNat n => a -> NestedIfs n -> Bool
```

and then

```
module M2 () where
import M1

instance C Int n where
    f = ...require that KnownNat (NestedIfs n)...
```

`NestedIfs` is not accessible to `M2` but maybe GHC should be able to
infer that `forall n . KnownNat n => KnownNat (NestedIfs n)` from the
general inference I mention above.

Comment: We would need `forall (p::Bool). Either (p:~:True) (p:~:False)` for that. I don't think one can achieve that without a singleton argument for `p::Bool`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? 1) What other types inhabit the `Bool` kind, 2) If  `Either (p:~:True) (p:~:False)` were a terminal of the Bool kind, would that actually help us at the technical level of helping GHC to automatically infer what I asked about?

Comment: By the way maybe take into account [this question I asked the other day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240533/infer-constraints-for-both-if-and-else-of-type-equality)

Comment: 1) I'm not an expert of this, but IIRC type families can cause e.g. `F Char :: Bool' to be stuck and fail to reduce to `True` or `False`. (Yes, that's quite annoying) 2) Assuming that anyway, one can pattern match `case proof of Left Refl -> ... ; Right Refl -> ...` and cause `p` to be instantiated with true/false, so that `If` simplifies and the constraint is found to be satisfied.

Comment: 1) If there is a bottom type inhabiting all kinds I don't think it manifests in the [same way](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7788#comment:16) as in values. 2) What you say only partially solves the problem. I will edit the question to demonstrate an example.

Comment: Cf. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492754/could-not-deduce-knownnat-in-two-existentials-with-respect-to-the-singletons-lib/41496362)

Comment: @fakedrake Regarding chi's first question: `Any :: Bool` (read as `Any` has kind `Bool`). Yep, it's ugly.

Comment: @alec thanks, you have even told me about it before I think. To give some [background](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#t:Any) for the future generations (and me when I desperately try to solve the same problem in a month or so): "`Any` [is] used to instantiate un-constrained type variables after type checking." eg `forall a. m a`

Comment: @fakedrake While that is true, anyone can make their own version of Any using a closed type family with no cases. The whole type level totality situation is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is not hard, but is ill-posed. What value do you expect to get back of type `c (If p a b) :: Constraint`? What you likely want to ask, is how to fill in the body of this

```
bisect :: forall b c x y. SingI b => Proxy b -> (c x, c y) :- c (If b x y)
```

Here, as noted in the comments, I am forcing `c` to be a singleton so that I can get `Either (c :~: True) (c :~: False)` (you may read my `SingI` constraint as enforcing that `c :: Bool` must be either `True` or `False`, which is unfortunately not a trivial request when at the type level since `Any` has kind `Bool` too). The `:-` comes from the [`constraints`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package. It is a way of saying that the constraint `(a,b)` implies the constraint `If c a b`. That is *exactly* how to express your request - you want a proof that two says **given `c x` and `c y` hold, `c (If b x y)` will also hold**.

Filling in the body of that function is actually very little code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds, TypeOperators, RankNTypes,
    ScopedTypeVariables, PolyKinds #-}

import Data.Constraint
import Data.Singletons.Prelude hiding ((:-))

bisect :: forall b c x y. (SingI b) => Proxy b -> (c x, c y) :- c (If b x y)
bisect _ = unmapDict $ case sing :: Sing b of
                         STrue -> mapDict weaken1
                         SFalse -> mapDict weaken2
```

Comment: Thnx! Is there a way to get rid of `Proxy b`?

Comment: @fakedrake Yes, you can just drop that argument out (and enable `AllowAmbiguousTypes`). To use `bisect`, may then need to have `TypeApplication` enabled.